# brics_actuator/JointPositions

Tags: ros, joint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I try to launch command : **"rostopic pub -1 /vrep/position_command  brics_actuator/JointPositions '{positions: [{joint_uri: arm_joint_1, unit: rad, value: 2.9}]}' "**
but there is this error :

> ERROR: invalid message type:
> brics_actuator/JointPositions. If this
> is a valid message type, perhaps you
> need to type 'rosmake brics_actuator'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148526/brics_actuator/jointpositions/) by [Peppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/14346/peppe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-04-03**:
Please give more details. Have you downloaded the package brics_actuator? Did you run rosmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've installed ROS fuerte for youbot KUKA, this package is into ROS fuerte for youbot KUKA. I'm trying to run rosmake  brics_actuator but it give me error :

> No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

---

Originally posted by [Peppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/14346/peppe/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/14346/peppe/) on 2014-04-04**:
HI, I've resolved my problem